# How To Efficiently Call a Function every X Seconds in Swift

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, timer

I am playing around with an iOS game using spriteKit and Swift, and I am having trouble updating a characters position. My plan is to have a simple (x,y) coordinate displaying the players position at the top of the screen and have it update a couple of times a second. I was able to make this happen using the following code:

```
updatePostimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.10, target: self, selector: Selector("updatePosition"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

The problem with this was that everytime the method executed, there was a noticeable lag in the screen. The updatePosition method is as follows:

```
func updatePosition(){
    positionLabel?.text = "X: " + String(Int(scene.player.position.x)) + " Y: " + String(Int(scene.player.position.y))
}
```

I cannot figure out why this is lagging. I would put the necessary code in the GameScene update method, but since this isn't a crucial part of the game, I was making an attempt to run this method on a timer in a different thread. If anyone has any advice on how to efficiently run this method on a different thread (other than the main), or how to get it to execute a few times a second without frame delay, I sure would appreciate it :)

Comment: What was your result of putting this mostly on a background thread?

Comment: I'm not sure how to run this on a background thread, I was just attempting to have it run independent of the main update loop (not sure if it would be on the same thread or not)

Comment: I think this has to do with the frequency you are updating. Try setting the `NSTimer` to update every `1/60` or every `1/fps`

Comment: @C.Greene You should avoid using NSTimer in SpriteKit because of reasons pointed by beyowulf. Also, NSTimer doesn't respect scene's or view's paused state, so it can require additional handling when pausing/unpausing the game. So, the right way is update: method or SKAction if fits to your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take advantage of the SpriteKit's run loop. SpriteKit will call:

```
func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval)
```

before each render pass so you can update any game state as you need. For more information see the [SKScene Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/update:). Using NSTimer is not advised as the timer is fired unevenly (i.e. whenever the system finds it convenient). For game state changes you want such changes to be in sync with the rendering engine. For a discussion of the sprite kit run loop see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013-502/) and why NSTimer is not great for animations, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2014-236/).